GOG - Multiple devices - Different game configurations for each device
I have (for now) two PC computers - desktop and a laptop. Desktop is a multi-monitor display setup. When I play on it, all GOG games (all games, for that matter, but basically only GOG can make it a fatal issue), without exception, are set to use 4k monitor. This monitor is number 3 out of 4.
But laptop has only one display (with number 1), which is just FHD.
Core of the problem: when I start GOG game on my laptop, I always have to redo graphics settings. If I am unlucky that day, the game will get corrupted and it will crash (though I admit it happened only twice). If all works as intended, game will allow me to change settings from 640x480 to 1920x1080 and I can continue.
But, when I'm back to that game on desktop, it will also revert to monitor 1 and will play merry hell on the rest of the monitors. Not sure why, but one of the 4k monitors will turn off completely and rest of the monitors will get numbers reassigned. What's worse: in-game monitor numbers do not correspond to order shown in the relevant Windows settings window (so monitor 2 in Windows becomes monitor 4 in game and from there confusion grows).
[Side note: It was worse before I upgraded monitors, because older one had limited resolution range and that reverting to defaults would cause it go blank screen]
Had it been just configuration in the game, I would stomach it. But this somehow touches the hardware layer in Windows, destabilizing it and quite often crashing some other apps that are running (I have multiple monitors for a reason).
So I am now asking if there's a way to uncouple configuration from GOG sync?
